# C: Stopping pointer incrementation

Tags: arrays, c, string

I'm currently working on my first assignment in C and I can't find a way past one problem. The goal of the assignment is to take in a string and reverse each word in the string while also capitalizing any alphabetical characters. For example, the string `octopuses_have#eight(())arms@` would become `SESUPOTCO_EVAH#THGIE(())SMRA@`. This process had to be done using pointers. Previously my biggest obstacle was getting past the non-alphabetical characters, but I have gotten past that. Now the issue is one of the pointers will not stop incrementing when I want it to. Here is the code:

```
void decoding(char *str){
        char *ptr = str;
        char *begin, *end;
        begin = str;
        end = NULL;

        while(*ptr != "\0"){
                if (isalpha(*ptr)){
                    char cap;
                    cap = toupper(*ptr);
                    *ptr = cap;
                    ptr++;
                } else{
                    begin = str;
                    end = ptr - 1;
                    int len = abs(end - begin) + 1;
                    reverse(begin, end, len);
                    if (ptr != NULL) //error occurs in this conditional
                    {
                      while (!(isalpha(*ptr))) //or in this loop
                      {
                        ptr++;
                      }
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
        if (*ptr != "\0" || ptr != NULL)
        {
            decoding(ptr);
        }
}


reverse(char *ptr_start, char *ptr_end, int length)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
    {
        char to_swap = *ptr_end;
        *ptr_end = *ptr_start;
        *ptr_start = to_swap;
        ptr_start++;
        ptr_end--;
    }
    
}
```

I used pythontutor.com to visualize the code and I found the problem. The `ptr` pointer variable increments past the last character of the string, past the `"\0"`, and points to `NULL`, causing an error with the message *"Use of uninitialised value of size 8"*. I don't know how to get it to stop incrementing when it reaches the end of the string. For whatever reason, the conditional `(ptr != NULL)` isn't working. I'm new to C, so I'd be grateful for any and all advice. Thank you!

Comment: `*ptr != "\0"` compares a character to the address of a string... Try _single_ apostrophes to denote a character... Haven't read any more of the code... (Or, get rid of the whole schmozzle and use `*ptr != 0` or even just `*ptr`...)

Comment: Further comment: Two operations: reverse 'words' and make uppercase. Your code would be simpler if you clearly separated these two distinct operations. No need to try to perform both at the same time!

Comment: This should have given a compile-time error:  `if (*ptr != "\0" || ptr != NULL)`.  The reason is `*ptr` has type `char`, and `"\0"` has type `char *`.  Presumably you meant `'\0'`.  The `||` condition also doesn't make sense.  You're checking if it's `NULL` after already using it.  That's like driving to a store, parking the car, then checking to see if you were wearing your seat belt on the drive there.

Comment: @Derek Kwon Do you want to write a recursive function?

Comment: `*ptr != "\0"` isn't even valid C so the root of all problems here is compiler misconfiguration or not paying attention to warnings. [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 1):

> *The ptr pointer variable increments past the last character of the string, past the "\0"* ....

Check this `while` loop:

```
                  while (!(isalpha(*ptr)))
                  {
                    ptr++;
                  }
```

This is what it is doing - if `*ptr` is not an alphabet, increment `ptr`.
Note that `isalpha()` returns `0` if the character passed is not an alphabet.
For character `'\0'`, `isalpha()` will return `0` because character `'\0'` is not an alphabet and the loop end up increment `ptr` past the string.

Instead, try this:

```
                  while ((*ptr != '\0') && (!(isalpha(*ptr))))
```

Other problems in your code -

This comparison is invalid `*ptr != "\0"` because `*ptr` is a character and `"\0"`  is a string. It should be - `*ptr != '\0'`.

You don't need this check `ptr != NULL` and also don't need the recursive call to `decode()` function. Just remove them.

There is one logical problem in your `decode()` function -
In `else` block, you are initializing the `begin` with `str`. Note that, it will reverse the string from the beginning to the character where `end` pointer is pointing. But your requirement to reverse only the   current processing word. Instead, initialize `begin` with `ptr` in the bottom of `else` block after skipping all the non alphabet characters.

Also, you forgot to specify the return type of `reverse()` function. Specify `void` as it's return type as it is not returning anything.

With above suggested changes, your `decode()` function will look like this:

```
void decoding(char *str){
    char *ptr = str;
    char *begin, *end;
    begin = str;
    end = NULL;

    while (*ptr != '\0') {
            if (isalpha(*ptr)) {
                char cap;
                cap = toupper(*ptr);
                *ptr = cap;
                ptr++;
            } else {
                end = ptr - 1;
                int len = abs(end - begin) + 1;
                reverse(begin, end, len);
                while ((*ptr != '\0') && (!(isalpha(*ptr)))) {
                  ptr++;
                }
                begin = ptr;
            }
    }

    printf ("ptr : %s\n", str);
}
```

With this, the output you will get is :

```
ptr : SESUPOTCO_EVAH#THGIE(())SMRA@
```

Note that the code can be written in much better way. Leaving it up to you to learn and make the improvements.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I thought recursion was necessary for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since strings are character arrays, and the array name is, in effect, a pointer, the following refactored code is a simplified approach to parsing a string comprised of uppercase characters, lowercase characters, and special characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void reverse(char *str, char *test, int k)
{
    int l = k - 1;
    int m = 0;
    while (isalpha(str[l]))
    {
        str[l] = test[m];
        l--;
        m++;
    }
}

void decoding(char *str)
{
    int i = strlen(str);
    int j = 0;
    char test[i + 1];                   /* Allocate a working character array size that is large enough to contain the whole string         */

    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        if (isalpha(str[k]))            /* If alpha characters are found, just convert them to uppercase and continue parsing each word     */
        {
            str[k] = toupper(str[k]);
            test[j] = str[k];
            j++;
        }
        else                            /* Otherwise - begin the reversal process once a non-alpha character is found                       */
        {
            if (j > 0)                  /* Only bother with the reversal process if a substring of at least one alpha character is found    */
                reverse(str, test, k);
            j = 0;                      /* Reset the substring index for subsequent substring searches                                      */
        }
    }
    if (j > 0)
        reverse(str, test, i);          /* Check if one last substring needs to be reversed                                                 */
}

int main()
{
    char test[100];

    printf("Enter a string to interpret: ");

    if (scanf("%s", test) != 1)
    {
        printf("An invalid entry sensed - program is exiting\n");
        return 1;
    }

    decoding(test);

    printf("Test output %s\n", test);

    return 0;
}
```

The key take-away here is the utilization of string lengths in lieu of attempting to utilize pointer locations within the string to acquire substrings and such.

Testing out strings that had multiple characters and single characters intermixed with special characters netted the following test output at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Discombobulate/bin/Release$ ./Discombobulate 
Enter a string to interpret: octopuses_have#eight(())arms@
Test output SESUPOTCO_EVAH#THGIE(())SMRA@
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Discombobulate/bin/Release$ ./Discombobulate 
Enter a string to interpret: octopuses_have#eight((i))arms@and?legs
Test output SESUPOTCO_EVAH#THGIE((I))SMRA@DNA?SGEL
```

Give that some testing.  As with all programs, there's always room for refinement.

Answer (score 0):

"*so I'd be grateful for any and all advice.*"

1. Be consistent with indentation. Code should be easy on the eyes.
2. Be consistent with declarations. (ptr is assigned, but `begin` & `end` declared then defined.)
3. The terminator of a C string can be tested with `*p` or `p[0]`. It's value is 0 (equivalent to `false`).
4. Don't use pointless variables. `*ptr = toupper( *ptr );` instead of `char cap;`
5. The `end = ptr - 1`, then `abs(..) + 1` makes a reader dizzy. Unnecessary.

As you're new to the language, here's a solution for you to consider:

```
void decoding( char *str ) {
    // 1. make uppercase
    for( char *cp = str; *cp; cp++ )
        *cp = toupper( *cp ); // try it. it works without needing 'isalpha()`

    // 2. reverse alpha runs
    for( char *cp = str; *cp; ) {
        while( *cp && !isalpha( *cp ) ) cp++; // skip over non-alpha
        char *bp = cp;                        // remember pos of 1st letter
        while(         isalpha( *cp ) ) cp++; // skip over alpha
        
        for( char *rp = cp - 1; bp < rp; bp++, rp-- ) { // now swap
            char ch = *bp;
            *bp = *rp;
            *rp = ch;
        }
    }
}

int main( void ) {
    char foo[] = "&^% abc def(&(&ghi..$"; // test leading/trailing non-alpha
    char bar[] = "abc def";     // test vanilla alpha

    puts( foo ); decoding( foo ); puts( foo );
    puts( bar ); decoding( bar ); puts( bar );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
&^% abc def(&(&ghi..$
&^% CBA FED(&(&IHG..$
abc def
CBA FED
```

I hope this helps you better understand pointers and their use.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still getting used to pointers, this will be a huge help.